# Login Spring Boot + Spring Secutrity + Angular

Tags: angularjs, login, spring-boot, spring-security

Qual a estrutura que se utiliza para a combinação Spring Boot, Spring Security e Angular Js para gerenciar o login sendo que a aplicação Spring será em rest.

O controller do login será no formato rest também ou será na estrutura de ModelAndView? Guardam os dados do usuário no $rootScope ou em outra variável? Caso seja este o formato podem informar um exemplo pois criei próximo a esta estrutura mas estou meio perdido, quando envio para a pagina de login apresenta problemas de injeção de dependências, tento logar e não consigo ver se retornou sucess ou error. Para o Spring usei

```
auth.
    jdbcAuthentication()
        .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
        ;
```

Utilizam algo diferente do Spring Security?

Obs.: O Spring está barrando conforme configurado só preciso saber como fazem essa estrutura. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se optar pelo estilo REST, você pode utilizar a autenticação via Json Web Tokens **(JWTs)**. Os JWTs tem várias vantagens em relação ao modelo tradicional de autenticação (via sessão). Por baixo dos panos, uma implementação de autenticação via JWT utiliza também o Spring Security, e é MUITO simples de ser implementada. Veja neste link como implementar autenticação com JWT, seus pontos positivos e negativos:
http://andreybleme.com/2017-04-01/autenticacao-com-jwt-no-spring-boot/